# $(this).click and $(this).bind in jQuery doesn't work properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have to come back to you relating to one of my older questions. I have a site, with tiles and when you click the tiles, a page come up. The thing is, it's working properly in every browser except Safari desktop or neither mobile. The thing is, when you click, you have to move the mouse in Safari to make the page appear and that's not how it should work :(

I copy here the full code (for other functions too, it might be related to the problem, but I don't think so), the version of jQuery.js I'm is 1.10.2. Thank you for your help!

Edit 2.: I've modified the code according to your suggestions, still does the same :(

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.tile').each(function(){

        // mouseOver
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            $('.tile-title', this).css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'opacity': '0'});
            $('.tile-image', this).css({'visibility': 'visible', 'opacity': '1'});
        });

        // mouseOut
        $(this).mouseout(function(){
            $('.tile-title', this).css({'visibility': 'visible', 'opacity': '1'});
            $('.tile-image', this).css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'opacity': '0'});
        });     

        // listening for click and showing the page (has to be done for every .tile too!)
            var bgcolor = $(this).css('background-color'),
                textcolor = $(this).css('color'),
                page = $(this).data('page-name');

            $(this).click(function(){
                $('.'+page).css({'background-color': bgcolor, 'color': textcolor});
                           //.find('.close-button').css({'background-color': textcolor, 'color': bgcolor});
                $('.'+page).css({'visibility': 'visible', 'opacity': '1'});
        });

        // if close button clicked, hide the page (parent div)
    });

});

$('.close-button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'opacity': '0'});
});
```

Comment: Why do you have `$('.tile').each(...)` nested _inside_ another `$('.tile').each(...)`? Why do you have `$('.close-button').click(...)` _inside_ the outer `$('.tile').each(...)`? That will bind multiple click handlers on each `.close-button` element. Also, the `$(this).onclick` mentioned in the question title won't work because jQuery doesn't have an `.onclick` method.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: Why do you have a `.each()` loop over the ".tile" elements *inside* another such loop?  That'll result in multiple redundant "mousedown" handlers being applied.

Comment: @nnnnnn because i've tried with the .onclick originally, but when I googled for this issue with safari I read, that it's better to use .bind('mousedown') instead.

Comment: @Pointy removed the 2nd loop from inside, the results are still the same :(

Comment: I've never had any problem with simple "click" events in Safari.  `$(this).click(function()  { ... })`

Comment: @j08691 just tried with the .on('click') and .on('mousedown'). same results sadly :( but this was a good idea!

Comment: @Pointy tried with .click(). same thing still :(

Answer (score 0):

Sp the issue is solved, it wasn't this script, it's the picture scroller which is messing up the things in safari. I just have to find a new script for that and prey, that it won't mess up the things.

So just for everyone, the jQuery library from slidesjs.com can mess up things in Safari.

Thanks for all the tips and help, to clean up my code!

Cheers Guys!